# How to run a method a specific time interval after page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

this method calling in page load.

pageLoad:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        run_after_pageload();
    }
```

my method:

```
public void run_after_pageload()
{
                //  code
}
```

Comment: one solution would be to set a timer in the Page_Load method that executes the run_after_pageload method

Comment: Use Thread.Sleep(30000). This will wait for 5 minutes

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. What are you trying to wait for?

Comment: If you only want to execute some code after the load process is finished, you can put it in the `LoadComplete` or `PreRender` event handler.

Comment: thanks, where is put Thread.Sleep(30000) ? in PageLoad or in method?  @inquisitive_mind

Comment: Look like you are looking for [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

in addition to use QueueBackgroundWorkItem (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem), you could use
HttpTaskAsyncHandler, and make use of async, and use await Task.Delay(xxxx).

Something along these lines:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PageLoadWithDelay
{
    public class DelayedLoad : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
    {
        private int _delay = 1 * 1000;
        public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var response = context.Response;

            await LongRunningDatabaseOrNetworkTask(....);

            await Task.Delay(_delay);

            await LongRunningDatabaseOrNetworkTask(....);
        }

        public override bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            throw new Exception("no implementation.");
        }
    }
}
```

and use this instead of a regular aspx page.

Answer (score -2):

You should have a look at the System.Web.UI.Timer.

[Have a look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. You should at least put an example code to make your answer meaningful.

Comment: I'm sorry, this won't happen again. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -3):

There are two options.
Option one would be to use a timer. This would allow you to specify the time period and if need be the interval. If you are only running it once you can just disable the timer

Option two. use

```
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

where the number in the sleep function is the time to wait in ms. 1000 ms = 1 second

Comment: You can use Application.DoEvents() to force the loaded objects to be displayed first but it is not the best option. I personally would use the timer but the sleep may be useful elsewhere.

Comment: do you have an example of using `Application.DoEvents` in asp.net?

Comment: When multi threading and i want to push results to the GUI before all of he processing is completed so that another process can use them allowing multiple threads to process at the same time

Comment: @Shon , i use the timer and i have only running it once , where is put timer.enable=false ?

Comment: @stuartd , no i have'nt example of using Application.DoEvents.

Comment: in your timer code. You can put it at the beginning so that if the function you want to run will take longer than the interval it will not run again. Also, that would be an example of where Appliction.DoEvents would be used. Function takes 20 seconds but interval is only 5 seconds then you want to stop the timer before calling the function